# Adding data based formatting to the FullCalendar jquery plugin events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am currently using the calendar to display volunteering opportunities. These volunteering opportunities only have a certain number of places and so eventually the opportunity will become full. When there are no more places left on a particular opportunity I would like the corresponding calendar event to change background colour (i.e places == 0).

I have altered the fetch method in my PHP to include the number of places so the FullCalendar plugin now gets handed:

```
{
    title: 'Cal Give Back Test With Space',
    start: new Date(2012, 7, 20),
    url: 'opportunityDetailUsr.php?id=4&gid=153',
    places:15
},
```

I'm unsure after a lot of fiddling as to what areas I need to adjust to achieve my desired change. If anyone with a better understanding of the plugin could shed some light on this for me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this using the `eventRender` callback. Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/MpfGX/

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I can't thank you enough ganeshk, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hey - np! You will need to place the `eventRender` in the JS code - where you initialize the FullCalendar.